# how to copy a result of calculation in excel without distortion of the result and then transpose it from column to raw?

Tags: excel, office365

I want to copy the result of the multiplication that I made in the example below , but it keeps showing me 0 and this is because it seems it copies the equation and not result of the formula.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you paste, there should be several paste options, and one (or more) of them should be 'values'.

Try pressing Ctrl straight after pasting.